# pfSense Squid https filtering ERROR - URL cannot be retrived

Tags: ssl, https, squid, pfsense

I have pfsense 2.3.5 with squid 3.5 running on it. I have implemented HTTP and HTTPS filtering: http works like a charm, HTTPS doesn't work at all. I have uploaded the certificate into the browser but when I try to brows any https website I get the error below

[image]

I have tried to change DNS as well but still the problem.
I have look around and all solution proposed they didn't work for me. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details (your actual configuration settings/error messages/log excerpts etc) to provide you with a good solution. - Please edit and improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved. (As a first *guess*: the invalid URL `https://http/` in your screenshot looks like typo somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

> SquidGuard is broken for https out of the box. You need configure Common ACL
>   Target Rules List Default access [all] to Allow, save. Then click Apply in General settings tab.

My best bet is that **Default access has no block page configured for some reason**. If anyone knows how to get Default access to deny working please let me know.

Here is my working SquidGuard configuration step by step tested on **pfSense 2.3.4-RELEASE-p1 (amd64)**:

**1. Download any blacklist - www.shallalist.de for example.**

- General Settings -> Blacklist options -> check to enable blacklist
- Put in Blacklist URL: http://www.shallalist.de/Downloads/shallalist.tar.gz
- Hit save.
- Go to Blacklist tab.
- Hit download (Black list url is already there)
- Wait for it to finish downloading.

**2. You need to configure your blacklist default to Allow state (The default state which is Deny all is what causes https://http/* error)**

- Go to Common ACL Tab
- Hit plus button on Target Rules List
- Scroll down to Default access [all], set access to allow
- Set other categories that you want to be blocked to deny.
- Hit save at the bottom of the page.
- Go to General settings Tab.
- Click Apply at to Top of the page so your settings will be applied from Common ACL Tab.

**Check if https sites load properly now.**

> Remember to clear cache from before playing with pfsense from your
>   browser or it will show you old state of web filtering.

Comment: That is exactly what I have